# How effective and secure is sending user information to facebook in pixel?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

I want to re-target my users based on their purchase on my website. For example, if someone purchases kids wear from my website, I want to re target that user, when I launch some offer in kids wear range.

I read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2016/05/31/advanced-matching-pixel/) article. This looks really effective as I can send my customers mobile/email and purchase category i.e. kids-wear to Facebook. Later, I can re-target these easily these users on Facebook if I have some offer in kids wear.

But I am worried about few things:

1. Is it correct to share my customer mobile/email with facebook. Any legal consequences of this?
2. Should I send both email/mobile? What if the user uses same mobile but different email for facebook OR vice-versa?

If anyone can share any case study of using mobile/email in campaigns, it would be really great.

Comment: probably not SO question. Few other sites in SE family exist

Comment: For the security aspect, look at [information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/). For the user contact studies, consider [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).